# primordials is not defined with meteor after build

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor

i've got a template in my work that uses meteor and i need to build it and run it locally using node

so i used

```
meteor build --directory --server-only ../output
```

and it was fine

and i went to output/programs/server folder and i ran

```
npm install --production
```

it was built and everything is ok

then i put my env variables in windows env and ran the app using

```
node main.js
```

in output/bundle folder

but i get this error

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:40:5
    at req_ (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\npm\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\npm\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:-25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.Mp._compile (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\runtime.js:99:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\runtime.js:46:33)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.Mp._compile (C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\GitHub\output\bundle\programs\server\runtime.js:99:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

i tried to update gulp to 4.0.2 but no luck

still the same error

can you help me solve it?

thanks so much in advance

Comment: Which node and npm version and meteor version are you using?

Comment: node v14.19.3
npm 8.18.0
meteor 2.7.3

Comment: Meteor does not work with npm 8, only with 6

Comment: oh i see, it works with yarn? i don't wanna downgrade my npm